# Gemfire cache pre-heat completion

Tags: gemfire

I would like to have one server and a few clients. The Server will be my own Java application that uses CacheFactory. I will be reading all my static data from a database and populating the cache even before it is requested by any client. While the cache is getting populated in the server, it would also be spreading among all clients that are connected to the server. Once the cache population is complete, I would like to give a green signal to all clients to start requesting data. Is there something I need to do so that the server sends an event to the clients or the clients generate an event signallig the completion of cache pre-heating?

Thanks,
Yash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to create a region on the server and the client (say `/server-ready`) for notification only. The client will [register interest](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/gemfire_nativeclient/client-cache/registering-interest-for-entries.html) for all keys in this region. The client will also [register a CacheListener](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/developing/events/implementing_cache_event_handlers.html) for this region.

When the server is done loading data, you can put an entry in the `server-ready` region. The event will be sent to the client and `afterCreate()` method on the `CacheListener` will be invoked, which could serve as a notification to your clients that the server is done populating data.

Comment: I still think the framework should introduce a way to achieve this without having such a workaround.